# Twilio incoming call not working in android voice sdk

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

i have used android voice sdk
[github link](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android)

if i click call button i am getting congratulatory message and not showing any notification like incoming call. Please help i am doing this from long time.

[image]

in twilio site it is showing correct but not getting incoming calls.

Comment: make sure you make a working twiml app

Comment: In twiml showing entries of from and to and showing no anserer

Comment: make sure you add a country code before dial , like `+919988776655`

Comment: @chiragsatapara this is app to app calling means i am calling from client to client calls

Comment: actually i am web developer and in my app , client to client calling is working fine , and it is depend on your twiml app

Comment: Is there any problem in push notification for getting incoming call?

Comment: may be for that you have to check firebase , you mobile device token is register correct etc,

Comment: may i know how to check twiml is working fine or not? i can see log information in my twilio site. i have placed log image in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The basics of the Quickstart application get you to the point that you make an outgoing call and the example TwiML Application returns a congratulations voice message, as you've discovered.

You now have to build on top of this in order to place calls to other clients.

First you need to update the server application so that you pass an identity to it rather than using [the default](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python/blob/master/server.py#L13).

Then you need to add a UI within your own application that can give you a choice of clients to dial. I don't know what your app does, so you need to figure how you want to display this to users yourself. You could just give them a free text field to type the name of another client into or list all active users.

You'll then need to pass the client name you want to call into the parameters when you [create the call](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/twilio/voice/quickstart/VoiceActivity.java#L340).

You will also need to update the server route to receive those parameters and place the call to the other client.

To cover all of this, I recommend following the full [quickstart tutorial for Twilio Programmable Voice on Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client).